# Given that $ x + \frac 1 x = r $ what is the value of: $ x^3 + \frac 1 {x^2}$ in terms of $r$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that $$ x + \cfrac 1 x = r $$

what is the value of: $$ x^3 + \cfrac 1 {x^2}$$ in terms of $r$?

**NOTE: it is $\cfrac 1 {x^2}$ and not $ \cfrac 1 {x^3} $**

Where I reached so far:
$$ \Big(x^3 + \cfrac 1 {x^2}\Big) + \cfrac 1 x \cdot\Big(x^3 + \cfrac 1 {x^2}\Big) = r^3 - r^2 -3r - 2 $$

Any hints??

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Moreover, please note that the proper TeX command for ensuring larger fractions is `\dfrac`, not `\cfrac` (the canonical use for the latter is in typesetting continued fractions).

Comment: @Lord_Farin, ok! will keep that in mind.

Comment: Excellent! Much appreciated. :)

Comment: I was afraid that someone would point out that this was a duplicate and that's why I gave that NOTE in bold!! So I was right! Lol :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g$ is a function such that $g(x)=f(x+\frac{1}{x})$ then $g(1/x)=g(x)$.

Your $g(x)=x^3+x^{-2}$ therefore cannot be written as $f(x+1/x)$.

Comment: But @Michael gives a contradictory answer...

Comment: Hint: can you solve for $x$ in terms of $r$?

Comment: But the problem is, I'll get two possible values for x. Now, that'd mean there are 2 possible expressions for $x^3 + x^{-2}$. Doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: That's my point - there isn't a single solution. You can get a solution if you allow $\pm$ in your expression.

Comment: Well then, that's what I'll do - take both solutions!

Answer (score 2):

The answer could be found by direct calculation:

$$ x = \frac{r \pm \sqrt{r^2-4}}{2}$$

$$x^3+\frac{1}{x^2} = -\frac{(- r^2 + r + 1)(r + \sqrt{r^2 - 4} + 2)}{2} \tag{$+$}$$

$$x^3+\frac{1}{x^2} = \frac{4}{(r - \sqrt{r^2 - 4})^2 + (r - \sqrt{r^2 - 4})^{\frac{3}{8}}}\tag{$-$}$$

**Edit1** Please note that the domain of $r$ is

$$r\in \{\mathbb{R}-(-2,+2)\}$$

for example, if $r=\cfrac{5}{2}$, then $x=2,\cfrac{1}{2}$ and
$$x^3+\frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{33}{4}, \frac{33}{8}$$

Answer (score 1):

Can you turn the first formula into a quadratic in $x$?
Solve that, for $x$ as a function of $r$, and substitute into the second formula.

Comment: Is $x$ a function of $r$? What is $x$ if $r=\frac{5}{2}$? Is $x=2$, or $x=1/2$?

Comment: No such thing is mentioned. Though I believe that it's like $x$ and $r$ are some constants that adhere to the given equation.